# Trigger usercontrol storyboard from inner contentcontrol in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, storyboard

I have two usercontrols:

Usercontrol 1: 
 - contains a storyboard animation in the usercontrol resources named "somestoryboard".
 - contains a keyboard that has to be slide up when someone clicks on a textbox in usercontrol 2. 
 - contains a contentcontrol where any usercontrol dynamically resides.

Usercontrol 2: 
 - Contains a textbox with an eventtrigger. When touched the storyboard from usercontrol 1 has to be fired.

Unfortunately the whole binding goes wrong in the second user control. I constantly get the message "couldn't find object of storyboard".

How do I set this binding right in usercontrol 2, or is this even possible in purely xaml?

Here are the two usercontrols:

Usercontrol 1:

```
<UserControl (some namespaces)>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SomeControl">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="aControl"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" >
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="500" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="800" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="70" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,20,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"/>            
    </Grid>

    <Controls:Somecontrol x:Name="aControl" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                           Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" UseAnimation="True"

                          Style="{StaticResource AnimatedControl}" />
</Grid>
```

Usercontrol 2:

```
<UserControl (some namespaces)>

<Grid Margin="5" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding InputMessage}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding InputResult}" InnerBorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" >
        <TextBox .Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TouchUp">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SomeControl}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBox.Triggers>
    </TextBlock >
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that that was possible with XAML alone, but I'm certainly keen to see if you get any answers that say that you can do that.

Comment: Try moving the `StoryBoard` to the `MainWindow.xaml` rather than it being the `UserControl.Resource`. HTH

Comment: Are these two brought together on their own parent template or anything so you could maybe reach it with templatedparent or findancestor or something?

Comment: The first one is the parent of the second one. Tried your approach but unfortunately didn't work.